# It is possible to get the user id without access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a simple facebook canvas app (page tab) with PHP, that posts something to the user's wall via `facebook.com/dialog/feed`. I'm going to make it simple, so I want to skip the `access_token` request and the `facebook->api()` call. I have to store the list of the users who shared the post.

Actually, it works fine without authorization, but I need to collect the user's unique identifier (and/or maybe the name), after the wall post. Is that possible, without requesting an access token?

After the successful wall post, I store the unique post_id, maybe it's enough for a sweepstake?

**Update after the accepted answer:** actually, the first part of the returned `POST_ID` string is the unique user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't get hte user name without them authorizing your app, and I think the same might apply to getting the user id.

The problem with storing the post id is that the same user could easily make multiple posts, which in a sweepstake is probably not desirable.  What I have found with similar projects is that users are happy to grant access to basic information if they want to win the prize.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda acceptable. The only thing I just can't understand is that I can post to the user's wall without `access_token`, but I can't fetch the user id, after a successful wall post..? This is weird.

Comment: You can only post to the users wall using the feed dialog, which keeps the auth stuff hidden.  This is allowed because it's not a direct posting method, to post directly requires authorisation with the `publish_stream` permission.  If the user id was returned but the feed dialog then it circumvent the auth requirement.

Comment: I done the project with proper authentication, but after all I just recognized, that the first part of the `POST_ID` string is the unique userid... I feel like an idiot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the POST_ID to contain the user id. POST_ID is intended to be an opaque identifier and is not guaranteed to contain the user id, and not all POST_IDs do contain it.